# OS X: How to use proximity of cellphone/iPhone to lock/unlock screen?

Tags: macos, security, automation, bluetooth

I'm looking for a way to get my Mac's screen auto-locked when my iPhone (which is typically on my person) gets out of close range, and to unlock the screen when the iPhone returns to close range.

Ideally the detection should be using bluetooth, as wifi would have too much of a range.

Answer (score 2):

There's a little tool called [Proximity](http://code.google.com/p/reduxcomputing-proximity/) that's been around for several years that people use for that sort of thing.

Comment: thanks. although it doesn't currently seem to be Lion compatible.